# Installing Windows 7 using Virtual Box without having a CD

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I would like to create a windows 7 virtual machine on my computer, but I don't have my install disk.  I currently have it installed on my computer in a dual boot with ubuntu 11.04 and was wondering if there is a way to create a virtual machine using the already installed version, without needing to procure a CD with windows 7 on it.

I am reasonably tech savy but would not consider myself an expert by any means.  If this is possible, would it be very difficult, and would there be any way to make it easier?

Comment: What you can do is something like this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=769883 but most here know nothing about windows 7 (and most things you need to do is inside windows) so this is likely to get closed. Btw this will also transform your current windows 7 install to Vbox only ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but it's not easy. You can check this guide in the VirtualBox Forum:

http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=33356

Note that this is quite offtopic and not Ubuntu related (it's a windows thing), you will be able to obtain more and better help in the Virtualbox forum or in some Windows site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd've made it a comment but I'm not allowed.

I'm using Windows7 through VirtualBox and I don't think things you'd like to do possible.

Another thing - as far as I understand - you can download windows7 from anywhere - it's perfectly legal - the important thing is whither you have a serial number. If you deal with laptop - it must be sticked at the bottom. Then after you'll install the Win7 with your number at VirtualBox - you'd have to make a call to your local microsoft office.

Comment: You are not allowed to have both a dual boot and a VM on a single license. It might be possible that you even need a separate license for VMs although I'm not completely sure of that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that. You can't run two VMs with it at any one time, but dualbooting and using it as a VM on the same machine will probably be legal since it's the same machine and you're only running one instance at a time. No guarantees though.

Comment: I didn't ment to have dual boot and a VM in the same time. I thought You'd get rid of dual boot, and leavy just VM. That's what I did with my laptop.